# КАК выполнить метод друг за другом?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть метод TIMER_funk()

```
public void TIMER_funk(int seco)  {
        this.sec = seco;

timer_sec.schedule(new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {      
     @Override
public void run() {
if(sec==15)
{Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("You need to work");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("15 minutes!!!");
    alert.showAndWait();}
        if (sec > 0) {
           sec--;
           int minutes = sec / 60;
           int seconds = sec % 60;
                SECONDS.setTextFill(seconds < 4 ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
                MINUTES.setText((minutes < 10?"0":"") + minutes);
                SECONDS.setText((seconds < 10?"0":"") + seconds);
               }else if(sec==0){timer_sec.cancel();return;}  
           }  
         });
        }   
      }, 1000, 1000);      
}
```

и мне нужно выполнить этот метод в другом методе, который уже создан, последовательно, друг за другом.

```
TIMER_funk(13);  TIMER_funk(15); //один после другого
```

Но тут есть проблема, когда я их использую как выше, то скорость обратного счета секунд увеличивается кратно, мне этого не нужно. Один метод отработал, второй начал.

Answer (score -1):

@Kolia, Вам нужен механизм простейших очередей. Код на java не могу привести, так как уже ничего из неё не помню, покажу на псевдокоде

```
// Создадим переменную в которой будем хранить задачи для последовательного выполнения 
Set<Timer> list = new Set();
// Создадим переменную, которая будет хранить активную задачу, если такая сейчас выполняется
Timer currentTask = null;

// Добавляем в очередь задачу
list.put(timer)

// При добавлении мы кладем её в очередь и проверяем есть ли активная задача
put(Timer task) {
    this.add(task);
    if (!currentTask) {
        currentTask = task;
        currentTask.run();
    }
}


// Метод run должен уметь при завершении удалить себя из очереди и попробовать найти следующую задачу и запустить её
run() {
    // Тут какая-то работа

    Timer newTask = list.popFirst();
    currentTask = newTask;
    currentTask.run();
}
```

Итого мы имеем самую простейшую систему очередей заданий, которые при завершении текущей, запускают следующее из очереди.